# FindBoost doesn't find boost

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clang

I'm trying to include Boost to my CMake script. When I run it with `Boost_DEBUG`, I get the following:

```
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2054 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/home/alexandre/Boost-for-Android-master/build/out/armeabi-v7a/lib;/home/alexandre/Boost-for-Android-master/build/out/armeabi-v7a/lib;/home/alexandre/Boost-for-Android-master/build/out/armeabi-v7a/stage/lib;/home/alexandre/Boost-for-Android-master/build/out/armeabi-v7a/include/boost-1_74/lib;/home/alexandre/Boost-for-Android-master/build/out/armeabi-v7a/include/boost-1_74/../lib;/home/alexandre/Boost-for-Android-master/build/out/armeabi-v7a/include/boost-1_74/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_system-clang-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_system-clang-mt-a32;libboost_system-clang-mt;libboost_system-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_system-mt-a32;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_system-clang-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_system-clang-mt-d-a32;libboost_system-clang-mt-d;libboost_system-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_system-mt-d-a32;libboost_system-mt-d;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_thread-clang-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_thread-clang-mt-a32;libboost_thread-clang-mt;libboost_thread-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_thread-mt-a32;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_thread-clang-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_thread-clang-mt-d-a32;libboost_thread-clang-mt-d;libboost_thread-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_thread-mt-d-a32;libboost_thread-mt-d;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_filesystem-clang-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_filesystem-clang-mt-a32;libboost_filesystem-clang-mt;libboost_filesystem-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mt-a32;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_filesystem-clang-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_filesystem-clang-mt-d-a32;libboost_filesystem-clang-mt-d;libboost_filesystem-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_filesystem-mt-d-a32;libboost_filesystem-mt-d;libboost_filesystem-mt;libboost_filesystem
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_chrono-clang-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_chrono-clang-mt-a32;libboost_chrono-clang-mt;libboost_chrono-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_chrono-mt-a32;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_chrono-clang-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_chrono-clang-mt-d-a32;libboost_chrono-clang-mt-d;libboost_chrono-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_chrono-mt-d-a32;libboost_chrono-mt-d;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_date_time-clang-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_date_time-clang-mt-a32;libboost_date_time-clang-mt;libboost_date_time-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_date_time-mt-a32;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_date_time-clang-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_date_time-clang-mt-d-a32;libboost_date_time-clang-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_date_time-mt-d-a32;libboost_date_time-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_atomic-clang-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_atomic-clang-mt-a32;libboost_atomic-clang-mt;libboost_atomic-mt-a32-1_74;libboost_atomic-mt-a32;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic
-- [ /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_atomic-clang-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_atomic-clang-mt-d-a32;libboost_atomic-clang-mt-d;libboost_atomic-mt-d-a32-1_74;libboost_atomic-mt-d-a32;libboost_atomic-mt-d;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic
CMake Error at /snap/cmake/1000/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system thread filesystem chrono) (found
  suitable version "1.74.0", minimum required is "1.48.0")
```

The libs are located at `/home/alexandre/Boost-for-Android-master/build/out/armeabi-v7a/lib`. The first search option on `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG`.

The files are named following the standard: `libboost_system-clang-mt-a32-1_74.a`.

I'm using the following configuration:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(Boost_COMPILER -clang)
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/alexandre/Boost-for-Android-master/build/out/armeabi-v7a)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/include/boost-1_74)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/lib)
set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE -a32)
set(Boost_LIB_PREFIX lib)
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So many options, could you first comment them all out, or until it builds? This could hint why findboost thinks it's missing.

Comment: Initially there were no options. I added one at a time trying to get some result. I'm grasping at straws here.

Comment: Can the library files be found in the boost installation root? You did install this using `./b2 ... install` I assume? What's the result of running `find -name "libboost_chrono*.a"` and `find -name "libboost_chrono*.cmake"` from the root of the boost installation? Were those library files built using clang? Do you require the boost compiler to be clang? Are you doing a 32 or a 64 bit build (printing `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` is an easy way to find out)? Are you cross-compiling?

Comment: @fabian I am cross-compiling to `armeabi-v7a`. I'm trying with this: https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android

Comment: Should it matter tho? I mean. Cmake doesn't check the file itself. Doesn't run a checksum AFAIK. So it should be able to simply link the libraries based uniquely on their names.

Comment: There are some checks in place in the cmake configuration scripts for boost that test, if the target system matches the system boost was compiled for. (If it didn't, you'd simply get linker errors later.) The only sources of error I can think of right now is no suitable libs being found or the libs not being installed properly; Crosscompiling could make a difference in the search behaviour, since cmake may look for libs depending on the sysroot.